# Regex match between two quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Here are the types of strings I want to match

(string are single quotes delimited (think `var str = '"hi, what"s up, what a nice day"';`)):

1. `' "This is a str"'`
2. `' "This is also a str "`
3. `'"So is this'`
4. `'"This should "also match un"til th"e last "'`

In each case it should capture whatever is after the first dquote if there's only spaces before it up to a last quote (which is completely optional).

Another thing, a string containing just `"` shouldn't match ex `'""""""""""""'` shouldn't match at all.

Also leading and trailing whitespaces are ignored both between the quotes and outside the quotes.

Here's the regex I have so far:

```
/^\s*\"\s*(.*?)\s*(?:\"\s*)?$
```

But it also gets `'""""""""""""""""'` so that's where I'm stuck.

What can I do to not match a whole string of just dquotes?

EDIT:

I think I explained what I want wrong, I want it to match a string of dquotes but not **capture** any of it

Comment: http://www.txt2re.com/index-php.php3.  That site might help - it lets you craft RegEx from sample input.  Also, for testing:  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your regex so that the content contains at least one non-" character:

```
/^\s*\"\s*(.*?[^"].*?)\s*(?:\"\s*)?$/
```

**Update**: If you don't want starting and trailing " to be captured, just allow several of them at the borders:

```
/^\s*\"+\s*(.*?)\s*(?:\"+\s*)?$/
```

Comment: I was unclear, I meant I want it to match the string but not capture anything. +1 for answering what I asked, even if it wasn't what I meant

Comment: No I mean that if the entire string is dquotes I want it to match the string but not to capture any part of it. meaning the matching array will have the match[1] element an empty string.

Comment: so I removed the [^"] part in the second solution again - what about this?